# MySQL COUNT() to return 0

Tags: mysql, sql, count, null

I have a query that looks like this:

```
SELECT
  app.application_id,
  j.job_number,
  j.job_id,
  j.job_title,
  j.job_city,
  j.job_state,
  p.person_id  AS candidate_id,
  p.first_name,
  p.last_name,
  app.start_date,
  ope1.percent_complete,
  MAX(CASE
      WHEN r.role_display_name = 'ENG - Recruiter' THEN
        (SELECT CASE WHEN COUNT(last_name) = 0 THEN
                   'Unassigned'
                 ELSE
                   COUNT(last_name)
                 END AS uname
           FROM users
           JOIN job_roles ON job_roles.user_id = users.user_id
          WHERE job_id = j.job_id
            AND role_id = r.role_id
        )
      ELSE '' END) AS role_3
```

My problem is that `COUNT(last_name)` will not return 0, because there are no records returned, so there is no value of `NULL`. All makes sense, however I have tried wrapping it in `IFNULL()`, `ISNULL()` and none of them seem to fix this problem. How can I get it to return 0 when there are no records? Do I need **another** subquery inside the `COUNT()` aggregate? I would really like to not use another subquery....

Comment: This won't work. You're trying to use the result of an aggregate function in a row context in your subselect. the COUNT() results will not be available until AFTER the entire table has been scanned

Comment: If you're using php to handle the contents, you can kind of cheat and use `if (!$lname_count) $lname_count = 0;`

Comment: @MarcB How do I check that a record exists for that condition then?

Comment: What is your full query?  You have aggregation but no `group by` and no `from` statement.  Also, can you better format your query?

Answer (score 1):

If understand correctly what you want you can try to rewrite it this way

```
SELECT ...
      ,MAX(CASE WHEN r.role_display_name = 'ENG - Recruiter' 
                THEN COALESCE(NULLIF(
                (
                     SELECT COUNT(last_name) 
                       FROM users JOIN job_roles 
                         ON job_roles.user_id = users.user_id 
                      WHERE job_id = j.job_id 
                        AND role_id = r.role_id
                 ), 0), 'Unassigned')
                ELSE ''
           END) as role_3
       ...
```

Comment: In this case, `COUNT(last_name)` can only return 0 when there are matches *and* in all of them the `last_name` column has no values (contains NULLs). I think it is more likely that the OP just needs to use a left join instead of the inner one. Other than that, your use of a NULLIF() here is very neat.